# Pop-up dialog when starting a server in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I stop popping up the dialog box in Intellij IDEA when I click Run or Debug ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

1) remove a mark in Show dialog checkbox;
2) click Update button, not Run or Debug.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Disable the **Show dialog** option in the application server run/debug configuration:

[image: show dialog]

Comment: I did it, but it doesnt help. The dialog still pops up

Comment: Don't click Debug again, just deactivate the frame or use Update action.

Comment: Yes, I have just realized it. Thanks!